# Logic behind the PHP code

Tags: php, variables, get, substring

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind the following code:

**Initial code**

```
            <?php
            $output_arr=array();
            $handle = fopen("../etc/init.d/bandwidthlimiters/rulestest", "r");
            if ($handle) {

                $i=1;
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                $test_string=$line;
                $test_string=str_replace(" htb rate ","@@",$test_string);
                $test_string=str_replace("kbit ceil ","@@",$test_string);

                $tmp = explode("@@", $test_string);
                array_push($output_arr,$tmp[1]);
                $i++;
               }

                fclose($handle);
            } else {
                // error opening the file.
            } 

            echo $output_arr[5]
            ?>
```

At the moment `echo $output_arr[5]` provides a printed value of "`5`" when taken from the file source listed. File contents shown below, under "New Output".

**New Output**

Instead of looking for values between `" htb rate "` and `"kbit ceil"`, I would like it to grab results based on the following terms: `" ceil "` and `"kbit"`

```
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 1kbit ceil 11111kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 2kbit ceil 22222kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:4 htb rate 3kbit ceil 33333kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:5 htb rate 4kbit ceil 44444kbit
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:6 htb rate 5kbit ceil 55555kbit
```

By using the sample lines above, the new result should retrieve "`55555`", instead of the original "`5`"

**Modified version**

I have tried a modification, as shown below:

```
                $test_string=str_replace(" ceil ","@@",$test_string);
                $test_string=str_replace("kbit","@@",$test_string);
```

However, this does not return any result. For future use, I would like to be able to manipulate this further to return different results again, in which case, any explanation of how to use this method would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `var_dump($tmp);` to see the problem.

Comment: @Barmar: array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "tc -s filter show dev br-lan" } I'm guessing that shows the requirement of "$test_string" are not being met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modification is resulting in this value of `$test_string`:

```
tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:6 htb rate 5@@@@55555@@
```

Notice that there are two `@@` sequences before the field that you want to retrieve. The first comes from replacing `kbit`, the second comes from replacing `ceil`. When you explode it, you get:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(57) "tc class add dev br-lan parent 1:1 classid 1:6 htb rate 5"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(5) "55555"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "
"
}
```

So `55555` is in `$tmp[2]`, not `$tmp[1]`.

Comment: I understand that now, thank you! However, the a dump of `$tmp` shows array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "tc -s filter show dev br-lan" }. When $tmp[2] is set, it returns a result of "NULL"

Comment: That's not what I get when I perform the dump.

Comment: `var_dump($tmp[2]);` returns `NULL`
`var_dump($tmp);` returns `array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "tc -s filter show dev br-lan" }` excuse the initial comment

Comment: Maybe you should be using a regexp instead of replacing and splitting.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting something different from me.

Comment: having broken it down, the error seems to be within:                 `$output_arr=array();
                $handle = fopen("../etc/init.d/bandwidthlimiters/rulestest", "r");
                if ($handle) {
                $i=1;
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                    
                $test_string = $line;`

Comment: it works perfectly when the line isn't pulled from a file and is hard coded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141906/discussion-between-reconnected-and-barmar).

Comment: Then apparently the lines aren't the same as what you posted. What does `var_dump($line)` show?